# How can I add a pager to the top of a forum?

Tags: 8, theming

I am using the standard forum module that comes with Drupal 8. The problem is, when I view a forum node, it shows the pager the bottom. I want the pager to also appear at the top.

The closest I've been able to come is editing the "comment--comment_forum.html.twig" template. If I put random text at the top of this template, then I can see the text appearing at the right spot I want. But if I put this:

```
{{ pager }}
```

Then nothing shows. So the comment--comment_forum.html.twig template doesn't know what "pager" is.

Does anyone know where the correct place is to add a pager to the top of forum posts?

Answer (score 2):

Pager is known within the "views-view.html.twig" file: /core/modules/views/templates/views-view.html.twig

If you are using a contributed or custom theme you can override that file and move the pager output where you'd like. So your new file would live here:
`/themes/custom/MY_THEME/templates/views-view.html.twig"`
 for example.

As near as I can tell there's no setting for this in core currently, although [it's been requested.](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1210980)

See also: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view.html.twig/8.7.x

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.7.x